# Freeglut error: fgInitGL2: fghGenBuffers is NULL

Tags: opengl, c++11, freeglut, mingw-w64

I'm transferring a program from OSX to Windows, but one error is still nagging me. The error occurs during run-time in gdb. Compiling and linking goes all fine.

> freeglut (C:\path\to\file.exe): fgInitGL2: fghGenBuffers is NULL

Outside the GDB environment it gives an APPCRASH (windows-shell) or Segmentation fault (mingw64-shell).

My linker flags are:

> -std=c++11 -lstdc++ -lz -lm -lmysqlcleint -lpthread -lboost_thread-mgw49-mt-d-1_57 -lboost_system-mgw49-mt-d-1_57 -lboost_regex-mgw49-mt-d-1_57 -lcurl -lfreeglut -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lws2_32 -lwsock32 -U__CYGWIN__

I'm working in msys2 mingw-w64. During runtime, the program tries to open a new window (at least a pictogram rices in the windows taskbar), but the construction of the window won't succeed. The program runs fine on OSX, where I use glut instead of freeglut.

Header (amongst others):

```
#include <direct.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
```

CPP (amongst others):

```
void interface::startInterface(int &argc, char **argv){

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize  (width, height);
    glutInitWindowPosition (1920, 0);
    glutInit            (&argc, argv);
    glutCreateWindow    ("TIFAR 2.0");


    LoadGLTextures();                           // Load The Texture(s) ( NEW )
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);       // This Will Clear The Background Color To Black
    glClearDepth(1.0);                          // Enables Clearing Of The Depth Buffer
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);                       // The Type Of Depth Test To Do
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                    // Enables Depth Testing
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                    // Enables Smooth Color Shading
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();                           // Reset The Projection Matrix

    gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat) width / (GLfloat) height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    // Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glutDisplayFunc     (interface::display);
    glutReshapeFunc     (interface::reshape);
    glutIdleFunc        (interface::idle);
    glutKeyboardFunc    (interface::processNormalKeys);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

There are some other parts in the program, like where images are loaded, but I think it will be to much information when I mention everything here.

Comment: What FreeGLUT version are you using?

Comment: @genpfault: From the defines of freeglut_std.h: FREEGLUT 1, GLUT_API_VERSION 4, GLUT_XLIB_IMPLEMENTATION 13, FREEGLUT_VERSION_2_0 1.

Answer (score 3):

It took me some time, but the cause of the problem was in the hardware. I was running on a virtual machine (VMware) and although the specifications said that it supported OpenGL up to 2.1 I found out that it doesn't support OpenGL at all.

My solution was to take an old machine, install Windows on it, and copy all files. It compiled and runs as smooth as a can.

If anyone else runs into the same problem I can advise to get it working on a native installation before virtualising. It can safe you a lot of time.

Comment: I get `fgInitGL2: fghFrameBuffers is NULL` at runtime when executing my program remotely using Remote Desktop on windows 8.1. Works fine when running from the machine localy. Can't seem to figure out a way around it without using VNC

Comment: Dear ObjectiveTruth, it has to do with the way Microsoft virtualizes the graphical card. Try RealVNC instead. See also https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/198132-OpenGL-and-Microsoft-Remote-Desktop